# How can I get these decimals formatted properly?

Tags: number-representation, rounding

It's nothing serious, but I was just wondering. I have a large number of floating point numbers which I write to a file. Mathematica writes each number with 17 decimal positions, which is way more than I need, so I rounded to 3 decimal positions.

```
a = Table[RandomReal[], 3]
a >> test;
b = Round[a, 0.001]
b >>> test
FilePrint["test"]
```

The output:

```
{0.125839, 0.407141, 0.567724}

{0.126, 0.407, 0.568}

{0.12583870135502573, 0.40714089222862637, 0.5677236611829515}
{0.126, 0.40700000000000003, 0.5680000000000001}
```

What I see in my notebook is what I expect, what's written to the file is not (though I know where it comes from). Is there an easy way to get rid of the non-zero digit in the 17th decimal position, so that all numbers have the same length?

Comment: `Round` won't help here (compare the outputs of e.g. `FullForm@0.072` and `FullForm@Round[0.072, 0.001]`). Since you want to change display aspects, consider one of the `*Form` functions, in this case perhaps `NumberForm[yourNumbers, 3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089018

Comment: @Roman - I don't think it is. I know that decimal numbers can't always be represented exact in binary. OP wasn't *why* this occurred, but rather *how* to get rid of it, more specifically in output. Thanks for your comment, anyway.

Comment: @MarcoB - I tried NumberForm[], but the function doesn't seem to work with PutAppend[], as it is a form of Print[].

Comment: Be nice to have a random seed that reproduces this behavior. I don't really doubt it happens, but it hasn't happened my trials. So I can't help.

Comment: @Michael - use SeedRandom[3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `Export` instead of `Put`/`Get`. I find that the latter are geared towards dealing with Wolfram Language expressions, rather than general input / output. As you mentioned, `Put`/`PutAppend` will export a `NumberForm` expression *literally*, rather than exporting its visual output.

Instead, collect the data to be exported in a variable, and then export them all at once with `Export`, formatting them as you wish. Here is an example:

```
Export[
 "test",
 {
   0.81745,
   Round[0.81745, 0.001],
   ToString@NumberForm[Round[0.817, 0.001], 3]
 },
 "Text"
]
```

The contents of the `test` file then become:

```
0.81745
0.8170000000000001
0.817
```

Comment: I just discovered the ToString[] solution myself :-). Thanks. About using Export, I write a header in the file before my data, so I'm put up (pun intended) with Put[]

Answer (score 0):

MarcoB's answer is almost there, but ToString[] add quotes around the list, which I don't want. I got rid of them by applying OutputForm[]:

```
OutputForm[ToString[NumberForm[a, 3]]] >>> test
```

The test notebook:

```
a=Table[RandomReal[], 3];
a >> test
Round[a, 0.001] >>> test
ToString[NumberForm[a, 3]] >>> test (* Marco's solution *)
OutputForm[ToString[NumberForm[a, 3]]] >>> test
FilePrint["test"]
```

and the output:

```
{0.4693043144910223, 0.35941460903748146, 0.4241708691371522}
{0.46900000000000003, 0.359, 0.424}
"{0.469, 0.359, 0.424}"
{0.469, 0.359, 0.424}
```

**Edit**
Note that while the last line looks like a list, it isn't, and we have to convert it again to an expression to use it as such:

```
a = OutputForm[ToString[NumberForm[RandomReal[1, 3], 3]]];
list = {x0, y0, x1, y1, a}
Flatten[list]  (* length is 5 *)
list = {x0, y0, x1, y1, ToExpression[ToString[a]]}
Flatten[list]  (* length is 7 *)
```

output:

```
{2513, 923, 2597, 931, {0.612, 0.687, 0.928}}
{2513, 923, 2597, 931, {0.612, 0.687, 0.928}}
{2513, 923, 2597, 931, {0.612, 0.687, 0.928}}
{2513, 923, 2597, 931, 0.612, 0.687, 0.928}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the output form is rounded to six digits, the last three being omitted since they are zero, this works:

```
a = RandomReal[1, 3];
a >> /tmp/test;
b = Round[a, 0.001];
OutputForm@b >>> /tmp/test;
FilePrint["/tmp/test"]
```